# realloc memory for a pointer which has been freed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

When I try to use `realloc` to allocate memory for a pointer which has been `free`'d, I get a segmentation fault. Although I don't face this issue if I use `malloc` instead.

As per my understanding after the variable has been `free`'d it is equivalent to a `NULL` pointer, then why is this unexpected behavior? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As per my understanding after the variable has been free'd it is equivalent to a NULL pointer.

A `NULL` pointer is a pointer whose value is `NULL`; standard functions like `realloc` know how to interpret this value.

A pointer to some memory that has been freed is now an invalid pointer; its value doesn't change.  `realloc` doesn't know that it's invalid, and will try and access it, leading to the seg-fault.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer that has been `free`'d is **not** equivalent to a `NULL` pointer. After calling `free` you'll need to set the pointer to `NULL` yourself.

If you're passing a pointer to `realloc` that has been `free`'d, but **not** explicitly set to `NULL`, you're probably passing `realloc` an invalid address, which it will try to use, resulting in undefined behavior, hence your segfault.

Comment: Man you're wrong, if the pointer passed to realloc is null, it's equivalent of a malloc. Look at the manual.

Answer (score 3):

No `free()` doesn't set the pointer to 0, You must do it yourself.

If the pointer passed to realloc is null, it will malloc it for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, a `free`'d pointer is not equivalent to a null pointer.  `free` does not modify the pointer passed in, so the pointer continues to point to the same memory location, which is now unallocated memory.

If you try to `realloc` it then the memory allocator will get confused and corrupt its internal structures, which is why you get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

This from man realloc(3) from a Debian Linux box should tell you all you need to know - basically don't free before using realloc()

> realloc() changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to
>   size bytes.  The contents will  be  unchanged  to the minimum of the
>   old and new sizes; newly allocated memory will be uninitialized.  If
>   ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all
>   values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then
>   the  call  is equivalent  to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is NULL, it must
>   have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer you pass into `realloc` must be one of two things: either a valid pointer that was previously returned from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, or else a null pointer.

If you free the memory, you need to set the pointer to NULL before you pass it to `realloc` again. `free` will not set the pointer to NULL (nor modify the pointer itself in any other way -- it can't because it receives a copy of the pointer, not the pointer itself).